# ionic 2 ion-range sensitivity

Tags: angular, ionic2

I would like to change the value of the ion-range when user moves the knob only and not when the user swipes the screen and accidentally touch the range slider. So, this is awkward for UX. Can anyone explain the best way to avoid this problem?

Thank you.